# CSS gap between list items in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-lists, listitem, gaps-in-visuals

I'm unable to remove the gap between the list items in IE7.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>row 1.1</div>
                <div>row 1.2</div>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <div>row 2.1</div>
                <div>row 2.2</div>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <div>row 3.1</div>
                <div>row 3.2</div>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
}

li
{
    list-style-type: none;      
    width: 100%;    
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;   
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;          
}

li:first-child
{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

li div
{
    float: left;
    width: 49.9%;
}
```

Comment: What effect are you trying to accomplish? Why are you using divs inside of an LI, you should likely be using nested lists. Demo your problem here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Hawxby a `li` can contain any element, the divs are less markup.. but the test is to view without CSS to see if the list still makes sense without,in this case I think it depends on the purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

float the `li` too

```
li
{
    list-style-type: none;      
    width: 100%;
    float: left;    
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;   
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;          
}
```

this will fix IE7 (it's a known issue in IE7) but it will also get other browsers to contain the child floats at the same time - (which they weren't doing)

added: ### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/ppBR3/) ###

Comment: +1 informative. Should probably add .clearfix to the UL, too.

Answer (score 2):

IE is really not the problem here.
What happens is you actually have a text node containing "\n\t\t\t" between each of your list items, and since those aren't unbreakable spaces IE interprets them as one " ", which is what you see.
Most of the time problems with IE are caused by the fact that it follows the specification, and people ... don't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>row 1.1</div>
                <div>row 1.2</div>
            </li><li>
                <div>row 2.1</div>
                <div>row 2.2</div>
            </li><li>
                <div>row 3.1</div>
                <div>row 3.2</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
li {
...
margin-bottom: -3px;
...
}
<![endif]-->
```